# Firebase data structure for sorting referenced entities

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

How should I design the structure so that users can view their subscribed channels' videos (e.g., youtube)?

The following is what I have in mind, but I'm uncertain about fetching just a few channels' videos at a time, from newest to oldest. With this, the user has to fetch all of the videos for each channel, and sort them on the client side. Is this even scalable?

```
{
  "subscriptions": {
    "user1": {
      "channel1": true,
      "channel3": true,
      "channel14": true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That sounds about right, if newest to oldest is based on when your user subscribed to that channel , you just need to add index to them (maybe instead of true) ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, I would recommend adding a "userVideos" *index reference* (not to be confused with the index I'm about to mention) where you keep a list of all videos the user is subscribed to, with an [.indexOn rule](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data) on the ``userVideos/{userID}/{videoID}.date` field.

Whenever a channel releases a new video, you should add the video to all of the channel's subscriber's video lists. When a user subscribes to a new channel, simply add all of the channel's videos to the user's videos.

You can read more about how denormalizing/flattening your data structures like this can be effective in [Firebase's data structures guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data).

```
- userSubscriptions
  "user1"
    "channel1" : true
    "channel2" : true
    "channel4" : true
- subscriptionUsers
  "channel1"
    "user1" : true
    "user2" : true
    ...
  "channel2"
     "user1" : true
  ...
- userVideos
  "user1"
    "video1"
      "date" : <date>
    "video2" : true
      "date" : <date>
```

Comment: I didn't realize for each new video, you'd have to add the video to each user who subscribed to that channel. Isn't this costly when there's a channel with over a million subscribers?

Comment: It certainly is a big operation. It can however be accomplished with a single update call using the [data fan-out method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/save-data#update_specific_fields).